# Installing 'CausalImpact' package had non-zero exit status. No useful info in error message

Tags: r, package

I'm getting a very unhelpful message when trying to install the CausalImpact package. This message appears after the kernel has been busy for about 5 minutes.

I'm using v4.2.3 of R, in Jupyter Notebooks, in a Google Cloud virtual machine instance.

options('repos') gives me the following: **$repos = CRAN: 'https://cloud.r-project.org'**

I've also tried install_github("google/CausalImpact") with the same result.

Any suggestions? Or any useful info I add to this question? The entire message is pasted below. Thanks

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Installing package into ‘/home/jupyter/.R/library’

(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ‘BoomSpikeSlab’, ‘bsts’, ‘Boom’

Warning message in install.packages("CausalImpact"):

“installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status”

Warning message in install.packages("CausalImpact"):

“installation of package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ had non-zero exit status”

Warning message in install.packages("CausalImpact"):

“installation of package ‘bsts’ had non-zero exit status”

Warning message in install.packages("CausalImpact"):

“installation of package ‘CausalImpact’ had non-zero exit status”

Comment: Blaming the error as non-informative when you didn’t explore the problems that were listed is on you, not on R. You need to find out why the missing dependencies are not being installed.

Comment: Nearly every similar question to mine that I've found is answered by someone saying, "The answer is in the full error message. There must be more information." I'm making the point here that the full error message has no useful info. Obviously it's listing dependencies that were not installed, but 'non zero exit status ' means nothing. I've checked that they're in the repository. I've successfully installed another package just to confirm that I can install anything at all. I did a lot of googling and reading similar questions before posting here.

Comment: So what happens when you try to install pkg ‘Boom’? The message from that attempt is probably more relevant.

Comment: It should not have been the case that the packages that were already in the library would have been reinstalled. If they are already there then they should be skipped over. The repository, i.e., some distant server,  is not where they need to be. They need to be in one of the three accepted library locations. (If you recently updated your version of R and did not update all of your packages you might "think" they were there but they might not match current  compatibility requirements.

Comment: Installing the Boom package alone produced a warning message that the installation had a non-zero exit status, and no other information. However I upped the memory of the virtual machine from 7.5Gb to 15Gb and tried again, and it installed. All fixed now, thanks.

Comment: If you install from a terminal command line you may get more informative error log.